# Retrieving the highest value(s) of each ID before a dropped value for that ID in BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

Before the value is dropped, I am looking to obtain the highest value(s) for each ID. Let's imagine the following Table and Rows:

```
ID | value | message_time
-------------------------
1  | 5     | 2023-07-01 10:00:00
1  | 7     | 2023-07-01 10:00:05
1  | 8     | 2023-07-01 10:00:12 <-- Highest Value
1  | 2     | 2023-07-01 10:00:14 <-- Dropped
1  | 4     | 2023-07-01 10:00:18
1  | 8     | 2023-07-01 10:00:28
1  | 12    | 2023-07-01 10:00:31 <-- Highest Value
1  | 5     | 2023-07-01 10:00:33 <-- Dropped
1  | 7     | 2023-07-01 10:00:38
1  | 9     | 2023-07-01 10:00:39
1  | 10    | 2023-07-01 10:00:40
1  | 14    | 2023-07-01 10:00:41 <-- Highest Value
-- NO ROWS --
```

I want to do it in BigQuery, and from the above data I expect the following result:

```
ID | value | message_time
-------------------------
1  | 8     | 2023-07-01 10:00:12
1  | 12    | 2023-07-01 10:00:31
1  | 14    | 2023-07-01 10:00:41
```

I have a table with over 10,000 unique IDs and each ID has more than 200 rows. I attempted to use the `LAG()` function, which worked well, but it's not useful to me because I can't apply a WHERE clause.

Thanks!

Comment: How are the dropped values defined? Is it every fourth entry from the beginning of the table shown above?

Comment: @Jan the drop can occur randomly after X incremental values.

Comment: Okay, but in order to obtain the highest value before each drop we need to define a partition of the table, i.e., a group within the maximum is searched. By which logic the dropped values can be identified, e.g. in the table above?

Comment: Same ID and ascending order for message_time.

Comment: and what is your where clause? without those details you will most likely get same LAG() solution that you already have

Comment: I attempted to utilize LAG to examine the previous row and store the value in a column called "prev_value". However, when attempting to use "WHERE value < prev_value" in a separate query, I found that WHERE does not function with LAG.

Comment: i see what you mean. in such cases you should rather use QUALIFY  (instead of WHERE) clause. see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select id, value, message_time
from (
  select *, countif(flag) over(partition by id order by message_time) grp
  from (
    select *, value < lag(value) over(partition by id order by message_time) flag
    from your_table
  )
)
qualify value = max(value) over(partition by id, grp)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the query. I tried it on the real data, but it didn't work properly. Here is my actual data [View Data](https://pastebin.com/eueVLc4F)